# perform the ng-repeat from a position in an array

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make an ng-repeat for a JSON of 10 elements. I would like the ng-repeat to run and display from the 5 element. how can I do it?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myarray>
  {{item.name}}
</div>

$scope.myarray=
[
 {"name":"joe"},
 {"name":"ana"},
 {"name":"buf"},
 {"name":"yei"},
 {"name":"jsi"},//5
 {"name":"sda"},
 {"name":"jofrewe"},
 {"name":"re"},
 {"name":"we"},
 {"name":"we1"}
]
```

the result should be:

```
sda
jofrewe
re
name
we1
```

Comment: there is probably a better option, but you can try adding `ng-show="$index>4"` (or even `ng-show="$index>max"` if you have `$scope.max=4;` in the controller)

Comment: put it as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `ng-show` to hide some elements.

```js
const app = angular.module("demo", []);
app.controller("test", function($scope) {
  $scope.myarray=
  [
   {"name":"joe"},
   {"name":"ana"},
   {"name":"buf"},
   {"name":"yei"},
   {"name":"jsi"},
   {"name":"sda"},
   {"name":"jofrewe"},
   {"name":"re"},
   {"name":"we"},
   {"name":"we1"}
  ];
  $scope.min = 4;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="test">
<input type="range" ng-model="min"
min="0" max="10"/>
  <div ng-repeat="item in myarray" ng-show="$index>=min">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually:

```
ng-repeat="item in myarray.slice(4, myarray.length)"
```

Not necessarily clean or beautiful though.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a real expression in the `ng-repeat` directive. So just use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the needed elements from the array:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myarray.slice(5)">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```